# ios -[NSArray componentsJoinedByString] with condition

Tags: ios, nsarray, concatenation

I want to use `-[NSArray componentsJoinedByString]` with some condition for example : concatenate all elements of my array with ", " except the last one where I want an " and ".

It python it would be something like :

```
', '.join(array[:-1]) + ' and ' + array[-1]
```

Is there a way or a method that would do the trick in one line, avoiding all the `if else` stuff ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `subarrayWithRange:` and `stringWithFormat:` to do the same thing. You do need at least 1 `if` to check the count of items in the array and ensure that you don't have an index exception.

Comment: I ended to use nested ternary operator to avoid lines overage with an `if`. It's pretty hard to read but np :D. Thx for pointing me in the right direction !

Comment: Nice one. I've created a category based on your solution below.

Answer (score 2):

try like this,i dont know is this effiecient or not but check once,

```
 NSArray *arr= [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
    NSString *string = [arr componentsJoinedByString:@","];
    NSString *str= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ and %@",[string substringToIndex:[string length]-[[arr lastObject] length]-1],[arr lastObject]];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the most efficient, but it is a nice simple solution to take an array of objects that have string representations and turn them into a comma separated list such as 1, 2, 3, and 4.

```
@implementation NSArray (MyCollection)

- (NSString *)stringCommaAndSeparated
{
    return [self stringCommaAndSeparatedUsingStringConverter:^NSString *(id object) {
        assert( [object isKindOfClass:NSString.class] );
        return (NSString *)object;
    }];
}

- (NSString *)stringCommaAndSeparatedUsingStringConverter:(NSString *(^)(id object))stringConverter
{
    assert( stringConverter );

    if( self.count == 0 )
        return @"";

    if( self.count == 1 )
        return stringConverter(self.firstObject);

    if( self.count == 2 )
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%@ and %@", nil), stringConverter(self[0]), stringConverter(self[1]) ];

    NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for( int index = 0;  index < self.count-1;  index += 1 )
        [string appendFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%@, ", nil), stringConverter(self[index])];

    [string appendFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"and %@", nil), stringConverter(self.lastObject)];

    return string;  // This is returning a mutable string, but we could copy it to an immutable one!
}

@end
```

Here is an example of this in action:

```
        // Results in @"1, 2, 3, and 4"
        NSString *str  = [@[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4"] stringCommaAndSeparated];

        // Results in @"1, 2, 3, and 4"
        NSString *str2 = [@[@(1), @(2), @(3), @(4)] stringCommaAndSeparatedUsingStringConverter:^NSString *(id object) {
                assert( [object isKindOfClass:NSNumber.class] );
                NSNumber *number = object;
                return number.stringValue;
            }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my category solution, based on Wain's answer:

```
@implementation NSArray (NSString)

- (NSString *)listStringUsingLocale:(NSLocale *)locale
{
    if(!self.count)
        return nil;

    if(!locale)
        locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];

    NSString *language = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleLanguageCode];

    if([language isEqualToString:@"en"])
    {
        if (self.count > 1)
        {
            NSArray *arr1 = [self subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.count - 1)];
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ and %@", [arr1 componentsJoinedByString:@", "], self.lastObject];
        }
        else
        {
            return self[0];
        }
    }

    return nil;
}

@end
```

I've added the option to add locale-based options.